# Additional conditions when using LINQ to SQL updates

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am quite novice to LINQ, but I have the impression that when updating tables, LINQ creates some SQL code like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

And I guess that the primary key is used within the `WHERE` clause. Let's suppose my tables/objects have a timestamp column and I want to check if the timestamp has changed since last time I read a particular row. I.e., my UPDATE statement would be:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value AND timestamp=my_timestamp;
```

Obviously the purpose is to abort updates when the timestamp has changed (meaning that another user has updated this row and my data is outdated).

Does LINQ support something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you look into using the built in concurrency functionality for LINQ to SQL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Read through that and then I'd bet that you're going to need to use this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.updatecheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx